# Почему ошибка в случае 1?)

Tags: python

Вот код:

Случай 1:

```
print(1)
a = 1
print(a)
print(a + 1)
```

Случай 2:

```
a != 1
print(a)
```

Почему в Случае 2 ошибка???

Comment: Потому что в случае 2 вы пытаетесь выполнить сравнение с несуществующей переменной

Comment: Если хотите сравнить, то с if. А тут бред.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка из-за того, что код:

```
a != 1
```

это значит, что `a` не равняется 1, а:

```
a != 1
print(a)
```

невозможно вывести `a`, потому что `a` не принимает никакого значения!)

Comment: Большое спасибо!)